# How to make box shadow over 2 elements but make 1 element position sticky?

Tags: html, css, styles

I want to put a Box-Shadow over 2 element, in the example below it is text "qwerewqrwqrewqrer" and "fdsafdasfdsafdsafas" but I want the "fdsafdasfdsafdsafas" to have position sticky. The problem with the below code is that position sticky is only relative to the box shadow div container meaning it won't be sticky relative to the page. Is it possible to make position sticky relative to the page and not?

Example code of what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#tableShadow {
  height:80vh;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #888888;
}

#sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

body {
  min-height:200vh;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id=tableShadow>
     qwerewqrwqrewqrer
     <div id=sticky>
        fdsafdasfdsafdsafas
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
Below are some images
[image: When you first see the page]

[image: When you scroll down a little]

and obviously when you scroll to the bottom of the page its just a plain white page.

Comment: Can you add expected output [screen shot or image](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/18/new-image-upload-support/)?

Comment: I don't know how to make an expected output, I will look on the internet for an example but in the mean time, it basically would be a box shadow container that is position: sticky in only the end half of it. Meaning that the other half will scroll off the page whereas the sticky half will remain on the top of the page. It might not be possible, I just wanna know if it is.